# JQuery Each setInterval Repeat Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, setinterval

I'm using a set interval function with jQuery to loop through a list of times on a calendar so that the individual divs can be refreshed. First I put this code on a page that was called via Ajax, but the function would never receive the new date variable set. It would just recognize the variable it saw when the page was first loaded.

Then I added the code to a click event on the main page, but then every time I selected a new date, the function would just run again, using the first date and then the second.

```
    $date = $_GET['date'];

    jQuery(function() {

    var data = {'9:30','10:30'};

    var date1 = $date;

 $.each(data, function(key, date1) {

   $("#"+key).load(\'cal.php?a=appointment&time=\'+key+\'&date=\'+date1+\'&x=\' + (new Date()).getTime());

  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#"+key).load(\'cal.php?a=appointment&time=\'+key+\'&date=\'+date1+\'&x=\' + (new Date()).getTime());
  }, 9000);

 });
```

Comment: 4 spaces before a line formats as code. `ctr-k` for a selection.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are 'over-escaped' some of strings. Try this code:

```
$date = $_GET['date'];

function Callback(key, data)
{
    $("#"+key).load("cal.php?a=appointment&time=" + key + "&date=" + date1 + "&x=" + new Date().getTime());
}

jQuery(function() {

var data = {'9:30','10:30'};
var date1 = $date;

$.each(data, function(key, date1) {

    Callback(key, data1);

    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        Callback(key, data1);
    }, 9000);

});
```

Comment: I should have cleaned it up a bit more.. The code is inside a php echo statement enclosed with single parenthesis.

Comment: The code that is inside a php echo is the part of code you posted or it's whole this code? Can you post all you have including the php code?